# Programming Portfolio

Tags: language-agnostic

I am currently a University student on a 12 month internship, before returning to University for a final year.  My questions is, how useful would it be to create a portfolio of home projects that can be used to support a CV for that firsrt graduate job?  Are there any employers on here that have any thoughts on this and also what level of work should be on display?  I'm thinking of going down this route to make me stand out from a lot of other candidates.  As a mature graduate (34 when I graduate) I think any slight advangate is a must.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, voting to close. Opinion questions belong on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah....sorry. Didn't realise that.  Will post it over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a developer that has been involved in interviewing candidates, I would say that having a portfolio of projects (home projects, open source, etc) is a great idea.

If you think about what a potential employer has to go on (a CV which tells a very limited story plus one or more interviews which are generally still pretty high-level), giving an example of your work puts out a few strong messages about yourself:

1. I can actually develop software
2. I'm confident enough in my software development skills to show them to you

By the way, I wouldn't worry too much about being a mature student -- this can just as easily be used to your advantage (i.e. you have life experience which new graduates will likely be lacking).

Answer (score 1):

i would say it is very useful;
put down any interesting personal projects on your cv,
that shows that you are keen to learn new stuff and likes to do programming in your spare time, as well as the additional experience you gained while coding them etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was once given a job and told on my first day that me and one of the other candidates had pretty much exactly the same skills and qualifications and had been coding pretty much the same kind of things.

The difference between me and him is that he coded everything in uni because he had to and mine was hobby code, which showed a little more willingness. That's what pushed me above him and got me that job.

so definitely worth the time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What sort of projects did you show on there?  I ma just about to start mine and i think the first one will be a Fractal Generator.

Comment: To be honest as a teenager I cared more about writing games because that was what I wanted to do - I didn't have any further plans other than to just have little games I'd written. But in hindsight it was a good idea because a game is still a reasonably large project, you need to make a lot of decisions regarding algorithms and data structures and you are processing everything according to a pretty tight deadline - everything has to be ready within 20ms. Of course doing little games also stops you getting bored whilst working on them :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be really helpful for landing a job.  You need more than a piece of paper to distinguish you in this economy.

When you're ready to look for a job, I would recommend this tool:

[Dynamic Presentation Portfolio](https://my.foliotek.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/User)